# Find shortest path with complex predicate (check simultaneously both node properties and relation property)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've built a graph with 40 mln nodes and 40 mln relations with Neo4j.
Mostly I search for different shortest paths and queries are to be very fast. Right now it usually takes a few milliseconds per query.

For speed I encode all parameters in relations property **val**, so ordinary query looks like this:

```
MATCH (one:Obj{oid:'1'})
with one
MATCH (two:Obj{oid:'2'}), path=shortestPath((one) -[*0..50]-(two))
WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE ((x.val > 50 and x.val<109)  ))
return path
```

But one filter cannot be done this way, as it should evaluate (on each step) property of starting node, property of relation, property of ending node, for example:

```
Path: n1(==1)-r1(==2)-n2(==1)-r2(==5)-n3(==3)
```

On step1: properties of n1 and n2 equal 1 and relation's property equals 2, that's OK, going further

On step2: property of n2 equals 1, but property of n3 equals 3, so we stop. If it was 1, we would stop anyway, because relation r2 is not 2, but 5.

I've used RELATIONSHIPS and NODES predicates, but they seem to work separately.

Also, I guess this can be done with traversal API, but I'll have to rewrite a lot of my other code, so it is not desirable.

Am I missing some fast solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your basic query is running quite fast. If you want to filter at additional steps, you probably have to add additional optional match and with statements to accommodate the filters. Undesired elements should drop out.